# Amelia Multiple Imputation - how to pass information about positive numeric variables, like age

Tags: r

So this is a silly question and honestly I do not understand why I can seem to figure it out.

I'm using the package `Amelia` in `R` to do a multiple imputation in my dataset. I figured out how to include nominal variables but I do not see how to include information about positive numeric variables. For instance, variables like age or symptoms_days should be positive and some outputs present negative values for these variables.

Anyone knows how to pass this information to Amelia?

Here is my code:

```
amelia <- amelia(data1, m=70, noms=c("Vac", "Radio", "Sit", "Sex"))
```

Sorry if the answer was right in front of my eyes but I missed it. I have read the vignette and look for an answer in the Internet but wasn't able to figure it out.

Thank you!

Comment: You can't force a fitting algorithm to do things inconsistent with the input data.  I think the answer from AEBilgrau suggests this.

Comment: Yes, obviously negative age would not be the way to go. I actually looked at the bound argument but I didn't understood its application. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that you need to use the `bound` argument.

From the documentation

> `bound` a three column matrix to hold logical bounds on the imputations. Each row of the matrix should be of the form `c(column.number, lower.bound,upper.bound)` See Details below.

and the details below reads:

> In addition to priors, Amelia allows for logical bounds on variables. The bounds argument should be a matrix with 3 columns, with each row referring to a logical bound on a variable. The first column should be the column number of the variable to be bounded, the second column should be the lower bounds for that variable, and the third column should be the upper bound for that variable. As Amelia enacts these bounds by resampling, particularly poor bounds will end up resampling forever. Amelia will stop resampling after max.resample attempts and simply set the imputation to the relevant bound.

So, suppose `Vac` is the 3rd column and needs to be positive and `Radio` is the 4th column and needs to be bounded between -10 and 10. You would need then need to write something like:

```
amelia <- amelia(data1, m=70, noms=c("Vac", "Radio", "Sit", "Sex"),
                 bound = rbind(c(3, 0, Inf), c(4, -10, 10))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was going to update my question with an example but you also provide one!

Comment: Great answer, upvoted. Can one set relative boundaries (as opposed to constant ones)? Something like "`Vac` is always at least twice as large as `Radio` (i.e. `Vac`>=2 x `Radio`)" in your example.